# Is it possible to construct a strictly increasing function $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ with some property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a proper infinite subset of $\Bbb N$, say $A=\{n_1<n_2<n_3<\dotsb\}$. Let $B$ be a proper infinite subset of $A$, say $B=\{n_{k_1}<n_{k_2}<n_{k_3}<\dotsb\}$ with the property that $k_1<k_2<k_3<\dotsb$.

> Question: Is it possible to construct a strictly increasing function $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that $f(n_{k_j})=k_j, \: \forall j\in \Bbb N$.

I am unable to construct/ product a counter example. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question but what about A=N, and B =N-{1}. And f is the identity function?

Comment: Or in other words A is so $n_i=i $ and B is such $n_{k_i}=k_i=n_{i+1}=i+1$.  And $f (n)=n $ so $f (n_k)=k_i $.  Why doesn't that satisfy.

Comment: Oh, A must be proper. Impossible. By hagen von eizens answer. Thee must be an $n_j $ in A where $n_j > j $. So $f (n_j)\ge n_j>j $.  The set B seems irrelevent as the indexes $k_i $ of B are just a subset of the indexes $j $ of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If $f$ is strictly increasing, then necessarily $f(n)\ge n$ for all $n$ (by induction).
Hence $n_{k_1}>k_1$ would be an immediate show-stopper.

Comment: Why would $n_{k_1}>k_1$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Ok I got it. One question : it is possible to predict whether $\{k_1,k_2,\dotsc\}\subset B$?